# What criterion did Abbe use?

Tags: waves, lenses, microscopy

For a microscope (correct me if I am wrong) the Rayleigh Criterion gives us: 
$$ R=\frac{1.22 \lambda}{NA_{condenser}+NA_{objective}}$$
But with the Abbe diffraction limit: 
$$ R=\frac{\lambda}{NA_{condenser}+NA_{objective}}$$
I know that the Rayleigh Criterion is based on when the first minimum of one diffraction pattern overlaps with that of the other. But what criterion does the Abbe diffraction limit use.

Comment: nice title ... is this Abbe diffraction formula is equivalent to the [wiki one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction-limited_system#The_Abbe_diffraction_limit_for_a_microscope) : $d=\frac{ \lambda}{2 n \sin \theta}$ where $n\sin \theta$ is the numerical aperture ?

Comment: There are a number of criteria you could use that result in the scale factors: proportions of encircled energy for Gaussian focusses will do it. But as to which one Abbe actually proposed and why, you might get a better answer on History of SCience and Mathematics: someone there might be more familiar than I am with the life work of Ernst Abbe. Born and Wolf might have more to say on this. The Ernst Abbe Wiki page says that he got his criterion *experimentally*. This is probably the best criterion of all for setting the scale factor.